# AWS ECS service setuop issues - works then stopped and raises CapacityProviderReservation alert

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am trying to move my service (written in .Net 6) to AWS ECS. In my company, we decided to take baby steps here and first move it as a single service with a single task and a single instance of it. We also want to use Rollout deployment that will mimic the current setup - so we first kill the service and then deploy a new version (new docker image) and if that fails we are not rolling back - just fixing the release. So old-fashioned without all the benefits of being in ECS.

What we created:

- ECS cluster with Linux EC2 type
- VPC network with NAT and Network Load Balancer
- Our service task has two docker images with Nginx and Net Core WebApi
- new CodeBuild that will build and containerize our Net Core Service
- Powershell script to automate the process

Powershell script is doing the following:

- triggering a new build from the branch that will result in a new Docker Image being pushed to ECR
- Stop service with command:

```
    $updateOutput = aws ecs update-service `
    --cluster $ClusterName `
    --service $ServiceName `
    --desired-count 0 `
    --deployment-configuration "deploymentCircuitBreaker={enable=true,rollback=false}" `
```

- Start service with the command:

```
$updateOutput = aws ecs update-service `
    --cluster $ClusterName `
    --service $ServiceName `
    --desired-count 1 `
    --deployment-configuration "deploymentCircuitBreaker={enable=true,rollback=false}" `
    --force-new-deployment
```

if the deployment fails we stop service again with the same command.

This is a kind of basic or even primitive approach but it is our starting point.

What is happening:

- everything works, we can deploy and redeploy the service and stop after failed deployment of a broken version
- service is responding to REST calls
- we see the logs
- **however,** after some time new deployment is failing, there are no logs and we are not able to do anything. Moreover, we are getting an alarm in CloudWatch: **CapacityProviderReservation (CapacityProviderReservation > 100 for 1 datapoints within 1 minute)**

And here we are stuck without a clue what to do next...

Any suggestion on how to investigate the problem's root cause? Or what to change in the setup etc. is highly welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use Fargate?  You can avoid having to worry about scaling the cluster entirely.